# Woocommerce change product image via php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change product image via php. But I can't get it to work.

```
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $yesterday = date("Y-m-d",  time() - 60 * 60 * 24);
    $jsondata = file_get_contents("730.json");

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
    $price = $json["AWP | Asiimov (Well-Worn)"][$yesterday]["price"]/100;

    $post_information = array(
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => "publish",
        'post_title' => 'test',
        'post_parent' => '',
        'post_type' => "product",
    );

    $image = media_sideload_image("http://www.technologijos.lt/upload/image/n/technologijos/it/S-49657/samsung-ssd-840-evo.jpg", 0, "The WordPress Logo");

    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);

    $attachment = wp_get_attachment_image( 18, 'thumbnail' );

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'total_sales', '0');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_downloadable', 'no');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', $price );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', "1" );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_purchase_note', "" );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', "no" );
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', "145");
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_attributes', array());
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_from', "" );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price_dates_to', "" );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $price );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sold_individually', "" );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_manage_stock', "no" );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_backorders', "no" );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock', "" );
    update_post_meta( $post_id,  '_product_image_gallery', $attachment  );
```

The last line doesnt work. And i dont know how to get it working. I tried changing different things, (I am new to PHP/ WordPress).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to set the featured image?

If so, you may want to use the function given in the [answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41300/14895).

**The Function:**

```
function Generate_Featured_Image( $image_url, $post_id  ){
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($image_url);
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else                                    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Generate_Featured_Image( '../wp-content/my_image.jpg',   $post_id );
                                                      // $post_id is Numeric ID... You can also get the ID with:          wp_insert_post()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to bryceadams answer.

Seems like that, for example, eBay's Finding API returns images whose URL has a structure that will not allow the command

```
$filename = basename($image_url);
```

to operate as expected because, what happens is, all URLs of the images have the same ending basename and the files get conflicted. I found out that the command

```
$filename = basename($image_url, '.jpg') . (string) rand(0, 5000) . '.jpg';
```

works better for many APIs. Hope it adds up and helps.